# How to avoid "Access to an undefined property" with text field format in PHPStan?

Tags: testing

I have a text field that I am setting inside an entity bundle.

```
  protected function doSomethingAwesome(string $value): void {
    $this->set('field_text', $value);
    $this->field_text->format = 'special_format';
    $this->renderField();
  }
```

PHPStan complained about this: `Access to an undefined property Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface::$format.`

So I tried using [webmozarts/assert](https://github.com/webmozarts/assert) because it's already included with Drupal to assert the property:

```
  protected function doSomethingAwesome(string $value): void {
    Assert::propertyExists($this->field_text, 'format');
    $this->set('field_text', $value);
    $this->field_text->format = 'special_format';
    $this->renderField();
  }
```

This fixes the PHPStan error (after installing [phpstan-webmozarts-assert](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-webmozart-assert)), but the assert fails in production.

I know I could disable this rule, but I already fixed all the errors except this one related to `format`.

How can I tell PHPStan that drupal text field has a `format` property?

**phpstan.neon**

```
parameters:
    checkGenericClassInNonGenericObjectType: false
    level: 8
    paths:
        - web/modules/custom
        - web/themes/custom
    ignoreErrors:
      - '#no value type specified in iterable type array#'
      - '#Thrown exceptions in a catch block must bundle the previous exception#'
includes:
    - vendor/mglaman/phpstan-drupal/extension.neon
    - vendor/thecodingmachine/phpstan-strict-rules/phpstan-strict-rules.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-webmozart-assert/extension.neon
    - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules/rules.neon
```

I realize this question might also be a fit for Stack Overflow, but since this is specifically about handling of Drupal fields and [PHPStan is now being used with core](https://www.drupal.org/node/3258232), I think it is a better fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this was caused by having a bad type hint on `hook_form_alter()`.

I had accidentally added `FormStateInterface` twice like this:

`mymodule_form_alter(FormStateInterface &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, string $form_id)`

and it should be:

`mymodule_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, string $form_id)`

Comment: Just want to note, you can also set the `value` and `format` in one go with something like `$this->field_text = ['format' => 'special_format','value' => 'text value'];`